# MySQL joining tables and selecting dynamic rows as column

Tags: mysql, pivot, prepared-statement

I tried to use a `prepare` statement, but got 500 error.

I have 2 tables:

1.Sales Record (table_sales_record)

```
    +----------+------------+----------------+
    | sales_id | product_id | shipping_status|
    +----------+------------+----------------+
    |    s1    |    1010    |     shipping   |
    |    s1    |    1011    |     arrived    |
    |    s2    |    1012    |     arrived    |
    |    s2    |    1013    |     pending    |
    |    s1    |    1014    |     pending    |
    |    s2    |    1015    |     pending    |
    +----------+------------+----------------+
```

2. Sales Details (table_sales_details)

   ```
   +------------+------------+
   |  sales_id  |    name    | 
   +------------+------------+
   |    s1      |   Sales A  |
   |    s2      |   Sales B  |
   |    s3      |   Sales C  |
   +------------+------------+
   ```

What I need is

```
   +----------+------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
   | sales_id |    name    |   1015   |  1014   |  1013   |   1012   |  1011   |
   |    s1    |   Sales A  |   NULL   | pending |   NULL  |   NULL   | arrived |
   |    s2    |   Sales B  | pending  |   NULL  | pending |  arrived |   NULL  |
   +----------+------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
```

The below SQL is what I have tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT `table_sales_record`.sales_id', 
GROUP_CONCAT('
 , `t_', REPLACE(product_id, '`', '``'), '`.`shipping_status`
     AS `', REPLACE(product_id, '`', '``'), '`'
 SEPARATOR ''),
' FROM `table_sales_record` ', GROUP_CONCAT('
 LEFT JOIN `table_sales_record`   AS `t_', 
REPLACE(product_id, '`', '``'), '`
        ON `table_sales_record`.sales_id = `t_', 
REPLACE(sales_id, '`', '``'), '`.sales_id
       AND `t_', REPLACE(sales_id, '`', '``'), '`.sales_id = ', 
QUOTE(sales_id)
 SEPARATOR ''),
' GROUP BY `table_sales_record`.sales_id'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT distinct sales_id FROM 
`table_sales_record`) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

I can just finish some part and not yet join `table_sales_details`, but I get the 500 error when execute this SQL query.

Do I follow the right direction? Can anyone help, please?

Comment: *"but return 500 error"* - Check your php logs, turn on error reporting, etc.  You need to get the actual error message before you can correct it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: I just running the sql statement in phpmyadmin but not the PHP

Comment: Can you clarify how *"I tried to use prepare statement"* is being applied in phpmyadmin?  How are you using a prepared statement there?

Comment: um.... It can't be running the above prepared statement ? may be that's the reason why I got the 500 error ....

Comment: But I have no idea how to get the above result neither..... Can help in creating the SQL statement?

Comment: I could just be unfamiliar with the terminology in this case.  Perhaps phpmyadmin has error logs?  Either way, "a 500 error" just means that something failed on the server.  It does not itself tell you what failed or why.

Comment: This code has to be inside a procedure, you can't run it as an ordinary query.

Comment: It reports Error Text: Internal Server Error. However, it works fine when I run a simple select statement. Therefore it could not be related to the server?

Comment: @Barmar You mean I should run it through php?

Comment: @joker No, I mean it need to be in a MySQL stored procedure.

Comment: @Barmar Any suggestion or direction can be provided?

Comment: Google "mysql stored procedure tutorial"

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling isssued of data display in application code.

Comment: @Strawberry display in application code?

Comment: Yep. Something like Php